# ¿Por que mi validación es incorrecta?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

Tengo problemas con la siguiente validación

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'ade';

// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(url,{ useUnifiedTopology: true });

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
client.connect(function(err) {
  assert.equal(null, err);

  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  const db = client.db(dbName);

  db.createCollection("students",{
    validator: {
      $jsonSchema: {
        required: ["name"],
        properties: {
          name: {
            type: "string"
          },
        }
      }
    }})

    setTimeout(() => {
      db.collection("students").insertOne({"name":"pedro"})
      console.log("agregado")
    }, 3000);

})
```

Y el error que obtengo:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Document failed validation
```

Comment: El error es claro, no estás trabajando correctamente con las Promesas. El método [`createCollection()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Db.html#createCollection) devuelve una Promesa cuando no pasas una función `callback` como tercer argumento. El método [`insertOne()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Collection.html#insertOne) también devuelve una Promesa si no pasas una función `callback` como argumento. Toda Promesa debe envolverse en un bloque `try catch` adecuado. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Prueba inyectando este objeto que te detallo abajo.

Yo uso estos `$jsonSchema` con esta forma. Te he añadido unos comentarios para que puedas saber que hacer cada propiedad.

Prueba y nos comenta si te ha funcionado.

```
/**
 * Schema de validacion para la colecciòn User
 *
 * @type {{collMod: string, validationLevel: string, validator: object, validationAction: string}}
 *
 * @param {string} collMod                              Nombre de la coleccion
 * @param {object} validator                            Objecto de $jsonSchema con los campos a validar
 * @param {string} validator.$jsonSchema.bsonType       Tipo de objeto
 * @param {array} validator.$jsonSchema.required        Campos requeridos
 * @param {object} validator.$jsonSchema.properties     Propiedades definidas por cada campo
 * @param {object} validator.$jsonSchema                Esquema de validación
 * @param {string} validationLevel                      Nivel de validaciòn:
 *                                                          - off: no se aplica las validaciones indicadas.
 *                                                          - strict: aplica todas las validaciones en todos los inserts y updates (default)
 *                                                          - moderated: aplica las validaciones en los campos existentes. No valida los campos ignorados.
 * @param {string} validationAction                     Accion al validar:
 *                                                          - error: El documento debe pasar la validacion en orden que esta siendo escrito.
 *                                                          - warn: El documento que no pase la validacion será guardado pero con un mensage de alerta.
 */

module.exports = {
    collMod: 'students',
    validator: {
        $jsonSchema: {
            bsonType: "object",
            required: ["name"],
            properties: {
                name: {
                    bsonType: "string",
                    description: "must be a string and is required"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    validationLevel:
        "moderate",
    validationAction:
        "warn"
}
```

Un saludo